# Angular 5 get class context inside class function

Tags: angular

I have this code:

**menu.component.ts**

```
export class menuComponent {
    menu: object;
    state: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.state = false;
        this.menu = [
            item: {
                action: this.action
            }
        ]
    }

    action(): void {
        this.state = !this.state;
    }
}
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of menu">
    <li>
        <a (click)="item.action()"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

what i need is to use the class functions and attributes inside **action** function, for example **state** attribute.

Comment: First you need to **call** the function: `(click)="item.action()"`. Then you need to make sure the action is bound to `this`: `action: () => this.action()`or `action: this.action.bind(this)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: sorry for the error, i already fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't understand why you have a function in state, you can use `bind`:

```
    this.menu = [
        item: {
            action: this.action.bind(this)
        }
    ]
```